# Signing APK file in Cordova v-5.0 CLI is not working

Tags: android, cordova, ant, apk, sign

i tried to add keystore properties into two files in the **platforms/android** directory.

```
key.store=Users/admin/workspace/android-keystore/keystore
key.alias=keystore
```

into

```
ant.properties
```

and

```
project.properties
```

File.

It worked fine in previous version, but not seems like the Cordova does not using ant in latest version.

So if i run command:

```
cordova build android --release
```

I always get only unsigned apk.

```
platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
```

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: is the keystore still configured in ant.properties after you have built the project? I launch command line tools to sign and aligne the app after the project is built.

Answer (score 13):

Because cordova now uses gradle, you need to create a file called release-signing.properties in your platforms/android/ directory

The settings looks like:

```
storeFile=relative/path/to/keystore.p12
storePassword=SECRET1
storeType=pkcs12
keyAlias=DebugSigningKey
keyPassword=SECRET2
```

You can also use JKS files:

```
storeType=jks
storeFile=mykeystore.keystore
```

For more information see:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use:

```
storeType=jks
storeFile=/absolute/path/to/my/file.keystore
storePassword=mypassword1
keyAlias=myaliasname
keyPassword=mypassword2
```